# Invoke internal midnight commander cd via shell script

Tags: mc

I'm trying to use a shell script to have `mc` cd into some directories,
be them virtualfs directories (e.g. ftp, ssh) or local directories. How should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mc` allows you only to launch a new instance with requested path open in one of the panels. For local files you can just provide the directory as argument:

```
mc somedirectory
```

If you prepend `sh://` you can open remote directories on other machines as well:

```
mc sh://user@host/somedirectory
```

This works from the command line as well as from shell scripts.

Comment: Not quite - I already have an instance of mc open, and I want create a script to cd into specific folders/virtualfs when I call it from mc. In a sense, I'm trying to re-create the directory hotlist, since I think the present one can not fulfill my needs (find-as-you-type for the items).

Comment: And needless to say, that whenever I try using mc [some-folder] it tries to open another instance, which is not what I want.

Comment: You did not mention that you want to change the directory if an *existing* instance. Sorry, I have no clue about how to interact with an already established instance.